# AMQP 1.0 plugin in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Is it possibile for RabbitMQ with amqp1.0 plugin, queues act like topics? 
[In this docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/AMQPF2FPresentation.pdf) -19th slide- I saw, Queue-s acting like topics, with non-destructive links. I just don't see is it able to(?), if yes >>  where and how can configure RabbitMQ to get this behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

Information provided in the [documentation](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0) is well enough to add plugins

In case if you are looking for adding a AMQP1.0 plugin to the existing rabbitmq docker image

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management
RUN echo '[rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_management_visualiser,rabbitmq_amqp1_0].' > enabled_plugins
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_amqp1_0
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate the AMQP 1.0 plugin using the `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_amqp1_0` command.

Create a config file named "rabbitmq.conf" in this path: $RABBITMQ_HOME/etc/rabbitmq/

Add this content to the "rabbitmq.conf" file that you have created following the above instruction:

```
amqp1_0.default_user  = guest
amqp1_0.default_vhost = /
amqp1_0.protocol_strict_mode = false
```

I followed these steps to configure my RabbitMQ to work with AMQP Version 1.0.

Documentation for reference:

1. https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0
2. https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file